# Why is it [名前を書いたつもりだったが、**書いていなかった**ようだ。] and not just 書かなかった?

Tags: meaning, conjugations

What does the 'contuative' form add to the meaning in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

[名前を書いたつもりだったが、**書いていなかった**ようだ。]
So 書いていなかった is saying that "it was not written"

I.e. the speaker is saying they meant to write it, but the paper was blank.

書かなかった would say= I meant to write it, but I did not (write it).

Comment: You mean, in the original sentence, the verb 書く is conjugated in the passive form?

Comment: YES, that is it, the second instance of 書く is passive.